# Connect to SharePoint Lists with OData

Tags: excel, odata, sharepoint-online

I have a DataSet, I have created an Excel spreadsheet using OData connection. Now I want to create a SharePoint List using this Excel data. I want the Excel and SharePoint List to be sync so that list has all the latest updates. Is there a way to achieve this.